# Update Create Method in Django Rest Framework for two nested serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've found many answers to similar questions but not to my specific one. I'm trying to update the Create Method for my serializer which has two nested serializers:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductSerializer()
    prep = PrepSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):           
        products_data = validated_data.pop('products')
        task = Task.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for products_data in products_data:
            Product.objects.create(task=task, **products_data)
        return task
```

I want to add the "prep" nested serializer in as well to be updated at the same time but I can't seem get the syntax right.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add `Task` model code and input data from browser / postman and more description (what do you want to achieve ? do you have some errors ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine, I think you are missing `many=True`. Does this work? (Assuming and `products` and `prep` should be many)

And also assuming that your models are structured like this:

```
class Task(models.Model)
    #fields

class Product(models.Model)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Prep(models.Model)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```py
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductSerializer(many=True)
    preps = PrepSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):           
        products_data = validated_data.pop('products')
        preps_data = validated_data.pop('preps')
        task = Task.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for products_data in products_data:
            Product.objects.create(task=task, **products_data)
        
        for prep_data in preps_data:
            Prep.objects.create(task=task, **prep_data)

        return task
```

Then you can send a request like:

```
{
    "products": [
        {"foo": "bar"}
    ],
    "preps": [
        {"foo": "bar"}
    ],
}
```